# python date time string to time format

Tags: python, datetime, time, format

I am converting the time to datetime.time format from my dataframe.
The original time format looks like this:

420,
441,
31,
158

something like this. So there's no sec in the data, only have hours and minutes.

I made a code to convert that sting to datetime.time format,

```
time = datetime.strptime(str(time, '%H%M').time()
```

It works without error but during analyzing the data, I realized something wrong when I apply the code.

For example, the originally recorded time was 01:58, but in the dataframe, it saved the form like 158. When I applied the code, it covert the time to 15:08, which is incorrect compared to original document.

But the problem is both 01:58 and 15:08 will save the form in a same value in a dataframe, threfore, 158.

So, how to deal with that problem?
It seems like there's no solution right now, except the original document have to be saved in a different time format.

Comment: you definitely have to solve problem with ambiguous input data first; Nothing can help you if 158 can be both 15:08 or 1:58

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered - first you have to find out the logical rule for interpretation of input data; when You can tell if 111 is 1:11 or 11:10 - only then you can start implement conversion - any of already answered might work - depends on input data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import time

test=[420, 441, 31, 158]

string=str(test[2])

if len(string)<3:
    h=str(0)
    m=string[:]

else:
    h=string[:1]
    m=string[1:]

timesss=h+"/"+m

aa=time.strptime(timesss, '%H/%M')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
print(aa) --> time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=31, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
print(aa[3]) --> 0
print(aa[4]) --> 31
print(type(aa)) --> <class 'time.struct_time'>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one approach using `str.zfill` assuming you have 4 digits.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

data = ["420", "441", "31", "158"]

for time in data:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(time.zfill(4), '%H%M').time())
```

**Output:**

```
04:20:00
04:41:00
00:31:00
01:58:00
```

Comment: and if its 111? is it 1:11 or 11:10?

Comment: @Drako. Thats a valid scenario. OP has to confirm this

Comment: Your code is fine - the requirements are unknown - as result - your code might work :) and might not :)

Comment: Why do you need `zfill()` ?